# C++ Console application

Tags: c++, console-application, password-protection

I want to make one username and password field in my program . I was wondering if there is a way to display the password field something like this " ********** " instead of showing it to me while I type it in the console .

Answer (score 0):

As I'm reading around and testing, you can't do it "platform independent". I found [this topic](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=225713) which explains it. If it's ok for you not beeing platform dependent, why don't you use that lib mentioned there (conio.h) and use getch?